# Almacenando ManyToMany fields en un formulario forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Estoy construyendo un formulario basado en algunos modelos en uno de los cuales tengo atributos con relaciones ManyToMany a otros.
La situación es la siguiente:

Modelo `CorporalSegment`

```
class CorporalSegment(models.Model):
    SEGMENTO_HOMBRO = 'Hombro'
    SEGMENTO_CODO = 'Codo'
    SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO = 'Antebrazo'
    SEGMENTO_MANO = 'Mano'

    SEGMENT_CHOICES = (
        (SEGMENTO_HOMBRO, u'Hombro'),
        (SEGMENTO_CODO, u'Codo'),
        (SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO, u'Antebrazo'),
        (SEGMENTO_MANO, u'Mano'),
    )

    corporal_segment = models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        choices=SEGMENT_CHOICES,
        blank=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Segmentos Corporales'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.corporal_segment
```

Modelo `Movement`

```
class Movements(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Movimiento'
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Movimientos'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

Modelo `Metric`

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Nombre'
    )
    value = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits = 5,
        decimal_places = 3,
        verbose_name = 'Valor',
        null = True,
        blank = True
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Métrica'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{}".format(self.name, self.value)
```

Mi propósito es poder almacenar en un formulario múltiples valores/instancias de los modelos `CorporalSegment`, `Movement` y `Metric` , por lo cual he creado el modelo `PatientMonitoring` de esta manera:

```
class PatientMonitoring(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey(...)
    medical = models.ForeignKey(...)

    # Mis campos que son many to many a los modelos en cuestión mencionados
    corporal_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CorporalSegment, verbose_name='Segmentos Corporales')
    movement = models.ManyToManyField(Movements, verbose_name='Movimientos')
    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics, verbose_name='Métricas', )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Monitoreo del paciente'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.patient
```

Este es mi archivo views.py en relación a las operaciones de escritura con el modelo `PatientMonitoring`

```
class PatientMonitoringCreate(CreateView):
    model = PatientMonitoring
    form_class = PatientMonitoringForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patientmonitoring:list')

class PatientMonitoringUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = PatientMonitoring
    form_class = PatientMonitoringForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patientmonitoring:list')
```

Este es mi archivo forms.py el cual en su método `save(...)` es donde creo que debo hacer más énfasis ...

```
from django import forms

from .models import PatientMonitoring

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class PatientMonitoringForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PatientMonitoringForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Save'))

    # I think so that here is my problem ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        patient_monitoring = super(PatientMonitoringForm, self).save(commit=False)
        patient = self.cleaned_data['patient']

        if commit:
            patient_monitoring.save()
        return patient_monitoring

    class Meta:
        model = PatientMonitoring
        fields = ['patient', 'medical','corporal_segment','movement','metrics']
```

Y mi template `patientmonitoring_form.html` es:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Crear Registro de Monitoreo de Paciente{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    {% crispy form %}
    {% csrf_token %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Lo que me sucede es que cuando deseo grabar un registro o instancia de `PatientMonitoring` en su respectivo formulario, los atributos `corporal_segment` (Segmentos Corporales) `movement` (Movimientos) y `metrics` (Metricas) en el formulario, no son almacenados (recuadros rojos), pero los demás si se almacenan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este comportamiento es algo extraño para mi, dado que a través del formulario de Django admin, el modelo PatientMonitoring si se almacena con la totalidad de sus campos, incluyendo los many to many mencionados.

¿Qué puedo estar ignorando al momento de almacenar valores en mi formulario `PatientMonitoringForm` en `forms.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba sobreescribiendo en forms.py el método `save()` en donde le estaba dando `commit = False` de esta forma

```
def save(self, commit=False):
        patient_monitoring = super(PatientMonitoringForm, self).save(commit=False)
        patient = self.cleaned_data['patient']

        if commit:
            patient_monitoring.save()
        return patient_monitoring
```

y si le doy `commit = False` no se guarda inmediatamente el formulario en el POST

Acorde a la documentación https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method,lo pase a `commit = True` y ya guarda los datos que deseo el formulario.

Pero también estoy acá guardando al paciente en una variable llamada patient que no uso para nada: En esta parte

```
patient = self.cleaned_data['patient']
```

Si no sobreescribo el método `save()` es decir si lo quito, el formulario también me guarda todos los campos que corresponden a los modelos de `CorporalSegment`, y `Movement`.

En ese mismo enlace que referencio en la documentación se habla de llaamar al metodo  `save_m2m()` cuando se tiene el `commit = False` y en mi caso asi estaba y cuento con dos campos en mi modelo PatientMonitoring que tienen relaciones ManyToMany a otros dos modelos (Movement y CorporalSegment)

Lo que dice es que las relaciones ManyToMany requieren que el objeto padre sea grabado primero y con commit=False no se permite hacer ello.

Tengo que mirar esta parte de `save_m2m()` que creo que es adecuada para lo que deseo.